# Facebook 'Deprecate offline_access' setting

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I can't find this `Deprecate offline_access` setting in my Facebook app settings.

Why can't I find it? **My migration settings look like this**:

[image]

However, in the **Facebook example given in the developer roadmap document**, the settings look like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?? I'm having such problems with this PHP SDK and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: What setting? Deprecate offline_access? It's right there in your screenshot.

Comment: @Prisoner, That is the facebook example screenshot.  I am just showing the difference.  I cannot figure out why there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook disabled Offline_access feature. 
Article -http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/
You may try this post for FB app creation http://www.123codings.com/facebook/how-to-create-your-first-facebook-application.html.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but that doesn't help.  I know they disabled the offline_access feature, but as I read here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ - They have made a radio button called 'Depreciated Offline Access' setting in 'Migrations'.  Why do mine look so different?